# Write/Draw by or with

Tags: prepositions

I have learned that peposition with is used in sentences like,
Write with pen, draw with pencil, etc

But I have seen following sentence in book.

> For Kids drawing by crayons is always preferable than sketch pens.

Is this correct or should it be with instead of by.

Comment: What book did this come from? The sentence is written very poorly. "more preferable" is awkward at best, "Kids" should not be capitalized, the word order is awkward, and as you pointed out, "drawing by" is wrong. I suspect the author is not a native English speaker (or if so, is not a good writer).

Comment: Agree with TypeIA -- for that matter, what is a "sketch pen"?